# Is there a way to keep my map visible while I walk around?

Tags: diablo-iii

One of the features I really liked in Diablo 2 was the ability to change your map position. You could either keep it in the upper right hand corner or switch it so that it was over-layed on the screen and your character could essentially walk around on top of it. Like this:

[image: Screenshot of Diablo II with a large version of the map centered on top of the character]

Is there a way that I can set my map up like this in Diablo 3? If not exactly like this, is there any option other than keeping it in the upper right hand corner?

Comment: I loved this in D2, I would make it so I could more easier 'edge' the walls around me most of the time. I hope there is a way to do this! I have not seen it as of yet though, all mouse input goes to the map it would seem.

Comment: Tap Tab really fast

Comment: Might I suggest playing Path of Exile?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, that feature was intentionally taken out by the designers because they wanted to avoid that situation we all know in D2 where we spend about 10% of our time looking at the action and 90% looking at the minimap.

[Source:](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4cz11Wv6VhEJ:eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3312964418%20&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de)

> You are very much correct in your statement that this was a deliberate design choice, Caelestis. We did not want to have the Diablo II scenario where people just stared at a dot on a map to guide themselves through an area. We made the map full screen, completely opaque and prevented commands from being sent while it is open to stop this from occurring. We also like the concept that your character has to take a few moments and stop so that they can get their bearings :)

As a bonus, you can always kind of see what areas you haven't explored yet in the minimap to the upper right of the screen.

Comment: Is that really why they took it out or are you just guessing? Do you have a source for that information?

Comment: I've read it, or seen it in a video (don't remember which it was) where Jay Wilson (I think) directly said that. Yes that's a lot of uncertainty, and I'm already looking to find it again :P

Comment: Hehe, I almost want to downvote this answer because I do not want it to be true :)

Comment: editing in the source now, via google cache

Comment: Their plan has failed! (maniacal laugh)  I'm still constantly starring at a dot on a map!