# How can I resize minimap?

Tags: diablo-iii

In my opinion minimap takes too much space in Diablo 3 upper-right corner. Is there a way to make it smaller?

Optionally - is there a way to make minimap behave like in Diablo 2 when it was constantly semi-visible and overlaying gameplay? Cos when I toggle it fullscreen my character stops responding shortly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to keep my map visible while I walk around?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/is-there-a-way-to-keep-my-map-visible-while-i-walk-around)

Comment: Part of the question is a duplicate. The main question (resizing), is not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, there isn't a way for doing either of those things.

Specifically, your second question is answered in more detail [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/is-there-a-way-to-keep-my-map-visible-while-i-walk-around).