# Can I click to move on the Main Map (M key) or Mini-map?

Tags: diablo-iii

Let's say I clear an entire dungeon level and know I can proceed safely all the way to the end, but am on the complete opposite side of the dungeon than the exit. In past Diablo games, there was a way I could click on the map or mini map, and my character would proceed the long distance to that location while I took a short break or sorted my inventory.

**Can I do this in Diablo 3?**

**If so, how? What is the keyboard shortcut to do so?**

Comment: The designers made the decision not to allow you to move with the map up.  No what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to click on the main map or minimap to move there, neither was there such an option in previous Diablo games.

In previous Diablo games you could, however, move with the main map open; but [that option no longer exists in Diablo III](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/is-there-a-way-to-keep-my-map-visible-while-i-walk-around?).

Comment: This is probably my most missed feature.  Searching for a specific dungeon becomes much easier when you can see the explored areas.

Answer (score -2):

You can by clicking "tab" or "m" and under 'map level' it kinda looks like a plus or minus sign. Now click the plus once or twice and then the mini map will pop up and display over your whole screen and you'll be able to move the map around.

Comment: Please don't use all caps, it makes it much harder to read and is unnecessary.

Comment: The question is not about moving the map around. It is about clicking any point on the map and having you character navigate to that point.